# Using Python openpyxl to search and Delete Unwanted Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

Using openpyxl, I want to delete all sheets containing some keywords.
My sheet title for example are

```
['ABC-123','ABC-456','DEF-123','DEF-456','GHI-123','GHI-456','JKL-123','JKL-456']
```

List of keywords for sheets I want to keep

```
['GHI','JKL']
```

In the end, if the code executes correctly. The remaining sheet titles should be:

```
['GHI-123','GHI-456','JKL-123','JKL-456']
```

My code example below:

```
file = 'z:\\excel\\test.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
ws = wb.active
list_of_sheets_to_keep = ['GHI','JKL']
numbers_of_sheets = len(sheet_names)
i = 0
for i in range(numbers_of_sheets):
    x = wb.sheetnames[i]
    s = wb[str(x)]
    sheet = str(s.title)
    if sheet[:3] not in list_of_sheets_to_keep:
        print('Deleting sheet: ' + sheet + '\n because it is not in the List of Sheets to Keep')
        del wb[sheet] # this doesn't work
        # wb.remove(sheet) # and this doesn't work either
        # del wb[title] # doesn't work either
```

I get this error for del wb[sheet]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\excel\test.py", line 31, in <module>
    x = wb.sheetnames[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and this error for wb.remove(sheet):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\excel\test.py", line 39, in <module>
    wb.remove(sheet)
  File "Z:\.virtualenvs\excel-kLb3DFP1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 233, in remove
    idx = self._sheets.index(worksheet)
ValueError: 'ABC-123' is not in list
```

and lastly del wb[title] doesn't work either:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\excel\test.py", line 38, in <module>
    del wb[ws.title]
  File "Z:\excel-kLb3DFP1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 292, in __delitem__
    sheet = self[key]
  File "Z:\.virtualenvs\excel-kLb3DFP1\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 289, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist.".format(key))
KeyError: 'Worksheet ABC-123 does not exist.'
```

Comment: Why is the code so complex? The IndexError is because you're reducing the number of worksheets whilst looping over the range of all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
ws = wb.active
sheet_names = wb.sheetnames
list_of_sheets_to_keep = ['GHI','JKL']
for i in sheet_names:
    if i[:3] not in list_of_sheets_to_keep:
        print('Deleting sheet: ' + i')
        del wb[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

### ** Just missing the save

```
'''
def remove_redundant_sheets(full_excel_file_name, redundant_sheets):
    file_exists = exists(full_excel_file_name)
    if file_exists:
        wb= load_workbook(full_excel_file_name)
        sheet_names = wb.sheetnames
        print("Work sheets in the book:\n", sheet_names)
        print("Redundant sheets:\n", redundant_sheets)
        for i in sheet_names:
            if i in redundant_sheets:
               print('Deleting sheet: ',  i)
               del wb[i]
        wb.save(full_excel_file_name)
        wb.close()


excel_file = r'C:\Train\test.xlsx'
redunant = ['info', 'red']
```

remove_redundant_sheets(excel_file, redunant)
,,,